# Nested pseudoclasses in Less css

Tags: css, less, pseudo-class

I am trying to use LESS CSS to write my CSS but i got a problem with nested pseudoclasses
I

```
.class1 { 
        &:nth-of-type(2n) {  
            .class2{  
            } 
        } 
    }
```

the output is:

```
.class1.class2:nth-of-type(2n) {}
```

but I want to have this:

```
.class1:nth-of-type(2n) .class2{}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That snippet already gives `.class1:nth-of-type(2n) .class2` for me.

Answer (score 3):

Not an issue. You probably had a version of LESS CSS that did not produce the correct code. Try the [online less converter](http://www.dopefly.com/less-converter/less-converter.html) and see that it works fine. Here is what I get:

(in)

```
.class1 { 
  &:nth-of-type(2n) {  
    .class2{  
      x:1;
    } 
  } 
}
```

(out)

```
.class1:nth-of-type(2n) .class2 {
  x: 1;
}
```